# readability of node.js asynchronous functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback, readability

I understand that we should not return objects in node.js asynchronous functions and that every path inside the asynchronous function should lead to the callback function. To solve the "pyramid of doom" problem to some extent and for better readability, is it ok to just say "return;" after calling the callback function so I don't have to put the rest of the code in the else block and skip indenting and get better readability. The code has been working fine so far but just wondering if there are any potential issues I'm overlooking.

```
(function(database) {
    var mongodb = require("mongodb");
    database.ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;
    var mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";    
    var dbconn = null;
    database.getDBConn = function(next){
        if(dbconn){ next(null, dbconn); return; } //already connected: return dbconn
        mongodb.MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl,function(err, database){
            if(err){ next(err, null); return; } //connection fail: return error 
            dbconn = {db: database,  
                      movies: database.collection("movie") }; 
            next(null, dbconn); //connection success: return dbconn
        }); 
    } 


})(module.exports);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are no issues, but you can argue about the readability.

```
if(foo) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

Is not much less readable than

```
if(foo) {
  // do something
  return;
}
// do something else
```

Although I personally think the first version is a better representation of the logic sequence and the only way to run code after the first **and** second alternative, this does not apply to your case.

It is fine to abbreviate the flow as you did. When using JavaScript, I make it even shorter:

```
if(err) return next(err, null);
```

As most callbacks should ignore data parameters if the `err` parameter is set, the following should be enough:

```
if(err) return next(err);
```

This is the shortest possible form and I'd prefer it over every if-else statement.

Comment: So is it ok to return a callback function like below without any side effects?    //return callback(err, null);

Comment: @nomongo. It's perfectly fine functionally in your case.  But if you think about it, you need to keep straight 3 different contexts -- the return value in the callback, the function that called the callback, and where that return value is going after the final return.  This can sometimes create mysteriously hard bugs to track down, and I personally don't like to think so hard.  I honestly prefer your original version with the "{...}", partly because it will pass JSLint/JSHint.  Again -- I don't like to think so hard.

Comment: Thanks @mjhm and @ still_learning. Eagerly waiting for node v0.12 so I could use generators..

Comment: @nomongo @mjhm No asynchronous function should return a value. Assuming `next` does not return a value, `return next(err);` actually returns `undefined` and is therefore equivalent to `next(err); return;`. So yes, it is okay to use one of the short forms, whether they'll pass lint or not.

Answer (score 1):

What you have looks fine to me. You just need to make very sure that every if/else code path in every callback has a "next".

At some point you'll probably want to look at avoiding the pyramid of doom by using either an [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) (more accessible) or a [promises module](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) (does more with less).